# How to install MDB2 for pear on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mysql, pear

I am trying to install MySQL, PHP pear, and I don't know how to install MDB2 on Windows 7. Should I install Wamp first?

Comment: Doesn't `pear install mdb2` work?

Comment: yes i try it but does not work

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score -1):

This one helped me a lot. I got mine working following this , along with a few tweaks . Try [this link](http://www.truecms.net.au/blog/mdb2/installing-pear-mdb2-wamp-server-windows-7-vista-xp-32-64-bit).

Comment: Please provide more detail/description in your answer, along with the link.

Comment: In that case, I am editing the whole answer again.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)